# shell pipe list of dictionaries to another python file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

i want to pipe a list of dictionaries to another python file 
how can i output that list of dictionary and read it as a list of dictionaries in the other file

this is the list

```
     [{96: {'p_user_id': 97,
       'product-id': 459715,
       'user_id': 97,
       'user_location': '980 belle plaine, dallas, texas, united states, '
                        '75448'},
  97: {'p_user_id': 98,
       'product-id': 350361,
       'user_id': 98,
       'user_location': '6225 midway airport, nashville, tennessee, united '
                        'states, 37552 '},
  98: {'p_user_id': 99,
       'product-id': 183572,
       'user_id': 99,
       'user_location': '5044 neva, sacramento, california, united states, '
                        '95022'},
  99: {'p_user_id': 100,
       'product-id': 563781,
       'user_id': 100,
       'user_location': '7531 9th, little rock, arkansas, united states, '
                        '72158 '}}]
```

Comment: How are those two files connected? What's their relationship? Is the one starting the other?

Comment: @zwer i want to get some data from this list and use it in the other file they are connected via shell pipe i print data in the first file as a list and want to recive this list in the other file

Comment: Do you know how to write to stdout and read from stdin?

Comment: `sys.stdout.write()` and `sys.stdout.close()` in the first, `sys.stdin.read()` in the second.

Answer (score 0):

It would help more if you've posted your code instead of the JSON, but here's a simple way to do it:

```
# parent.py
import json
import subprocess

transfer_dict = {"name": "Bob", "msg": "Hello"}  # dict to transfer

# start our sub-process calling the child.py
proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", "child.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
# serialize to JSON, send to the subprocess and wait for a response
stdout, _ = proc.communicate(json.dumps(transfer_dict))

print("child.py responded with: " + stdout)  # finally, print out the response
```

Then write the child process:

```
# child.py
import json

data = input()  # awaiting input from parent.py, use raw_input() on Python 2.x

transfer_dict = json.loads(data)  # deserialize back to dict

# print out what we've received
print("Hey {}, {} to you too!".format(transfer_dict["name"], transfer_dict["msg"]))
```

I'm using JSON because it's less of a hassle than pickle and you've tagged it in your question. Running this will produce:

```
child.py responded with: Hey Bob, Hello to you too!
```

Proving that the `transfer_dict` dictionary has been transferred successfully.

Comment: That's if the OP's first script starts the second script itself, instead of an external shell script starting them both and setting up the pipeline. I don't believe it's clear which of these scenarios is the case from the question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - agree, but even if the script is not running the other, the transferring logic would be pretty much the same - print to STDOUT from one script, collect on STDIN in the other.

Comment: To be sure, but there are some details -- ie. the need to close stdout after writing to it -- that might make it appropriate to show both forms explicitly.